# Redis-nodes went out of cluster

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I have a setup with 3 redis servers and 3 redis sentinels on each node.In the beginning we have one master node and two slave nodes, but after some time all the redis nodes went out of cluster and goes into slave mode.
I don't know why this is happening, am I missing something here?

Redis-Server configurations:

```
Redis-Server A (master node)
Redis-Server B (slaveof node A)
Redis-Server C (slaveof node A)
```

Redis-Sentinel Configuration for all three nodes are:

```
sentinel monitor Redis-Cluster ip-of-master-node 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds Redis-Cluster 2000
sentinel failover-timeout Redis-Cluster 2000
sentinel parallel-syncs Redis-Cluster 1
bind ip-of-interface
```

Comment: Why C is `slaveof B` instead of `slave of A` ?

Comment: @Rhangaun i corrected it but still i am getting the same issue.